# Quickest way to create Plist file from a table

Tags: plist

I've got a table of data in an Excel spreadsheet. It's a uniform set of data where each row values for each of the columns.

Is there a Plist editor that can view Plist files in a tabular format so it's easier to edit the data (given I have thousands of rows). The form view in Xcode is too clunky and editing a Plist file in a text editor where I see tags everywhere is also cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

Try to this, I have not work on this but, I got this links on search. May it will help you. If it is work. Please shared your solution. It will help to others. Thanks

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://t.yctin.com/en/excel/to-plist/&ved=2ahUKEwiVubj4_cTjAhUKq48KHTHGC8wQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw2nS4vkbr4v4Ky9yusgRQYL

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure what to input in my spreadsheet for a BOOLEAN field though, it interpreted FALSE as a string "FALSE".